# Subscript out of range on the line beginning wb.Worksheets("ws").Sort

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort a range so the columns are in alphabetical order.

The following code, selects the desired range, but doesn't change the order of the columns.

I've searched for other examples, but they all refer to ordering the contents of a column (e.g. sorting rows).  I want to re-arrange the columns themselves.

The following script throws an error

> Subscript out of range

on the line beginning `wb.Worksheets("ws").Sort.`

```
Sub AITransaction()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Integer

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet

lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

wb.Worksheets("ws").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A1:E1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With wb.Worksheets("ws").Sort
    .SetRange ws.Range("A1:E" & lastrow)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `ws` is a worksheet variable. You don't want it inside `Worksheets`.

Comment: i.e. change `wb.Worksheets("ws")` to `ws`

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you both

Comment: Yes, find a thousand sorting examples on the internet and you will find they ` "all refer to ordering the contents of a column" ` because there's no reason to do other otherwise.  To demonstrate, we'll do a reverse sort without sorting by contents.... First turn your back to the computer.  Now look at the screen over shoulder by using a mirror.  If you look closely, you'll see the columns are reverse sorted, but what value does that serve?  Nobody would take you seriously if you sorted like that.  Keep the columns where they are and do the ordering by the contents, that's what I say! =P